# How can I remember the list position in a Compose LazyColumn using Paging 3 LazyPagingItems?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-paging, android-paging-3

I have a function like:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun LazyElementList(data: Flow<PagingData<Element>>) {
    val scrollState = rememberLazyListState()
    val elements = data.collectAsLazyPagingItems()

    LazyColumn(state = scrollState) {
        items(elements) {
            DisplayElement(it)
        }
    }
}
```

I would like when navigating to another screen and back to maintain the place in the list.

Unexpectedly, the value of `scrollState` is maintained when visiting child screens. If it wasn't, it should be hoisted, probably into the ViewModel.

Answer (score 2):

In the code in the question `scrollState` will be reset to the beginning of the list because there are no items in the list on the first composition. You need to wait to display the list until the elements are loaded.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun LazyElementList(data: Flow<PagingData<Element>>) {
    val scrollState = rememberLazyListState()
    val elements = data.collectAsLazyPagingItems()

    if (elements.isLoading) {
        DisplayLoadingMessage()
    } else {
        LazyColumn(state = scrollState) {
            items(elements) {
                DisplayElement(it)
            }
        }
    }
}

fun LazyPagingItems.isLoading(): Boolean
    get() = loadState.refresh is LoadState.Loading
```